# Unity throwing an indexoutofbounds error on a list/array of gameobjects when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public void SwitchWeapon(int index)
{
    Debug.Log(index);
    foreach(GameObject weapon in weapons)
    {
        weapon.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    }
    pc.weapon = weapons[0];
    weapons[index].GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
}
```

This code should set `pc.weapon(a gameobject)` to `weapons[0]`, a list of gameobjects. However, it throws an indexoutofbounds error.

When I run `debug.log` on the list, it returns `[]`, but when I run `debug.log(weapons[0].name)`, it returns the correct name. I tried switching from an array to a list, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: What does index logs?, what's the length of weapons?. Is index running from 0 or from 1?

Comment: If `weapons[0].name` does not throw an error then the problem is probably on the last line - `weapons[index]`. Maybe you can add a check before this line and make sure it is not causing the error: `if weapons.Len is > index ...`

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is that I'm calling switchweapon before its start method, which instantiates weapons. How can I make sure that the start method has run before I try and switch? @dimitar.d

Comment: Where are you presently calling `SwitchWeapon()`? Maybe you should move initialization of `weapons` into Awake() and move the `SwitchWeapon()` call into Start().

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<whatever-it-is> weapons = new List<whatever-it-is>();
```

and you can add an if statement before getting weapons items,
like:

```
if(index >= 0 && index < weapons.count)
{
    //weapons[index]......
}
```